# Async function not behaving as expected in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I have this simple code:

```
(async ()=>{
    const five = await printHello()
    console.log(`five: ${five}`);
})()

async function printHello(){
    console.log('Hello World')
    return 5;
}

console.log("App started");
```

My expectation is that it should print :

```
App started    
Hello World
five: 5
```

As the anonymous function that gets executed is marked async.

However it prints, even after multiple trials :

```
Hello World
App started
five: 5
```

Can some one please explain me why this is happening ?

Comment: It's probably because the code is executed from top to bottom, hence the "Hello World" message is shown before "App started".

Comment: @Edric yeah but when you mark it as async, the call goes to next line, and async funct gets executed on next tick of event loop.

Answer (score 4):

First, you call `printHello()`.

Then you call `console.log('Hello World')` which logs.

Then `return 5;` which resolves the promise.

Then you `const five = await ...` which awaits the promise returned above. This is a microtask so it gets queued up and the async function goes to sleep.

The IIFE finishes running, so the outer function continues with `console.log("App started");` which logs App started.

Then the outer function finishes, so the microtask is pulled off the queue and the async function wakes up.

The resolved value from the promise is assigned and `` console.log(`five: ${five}`); `` logs it.

See [Timing from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Timing) for further reading.

Comment: what about the async on anonymous immediately executed function ? it should create microtask and gets queued for next tick. 'App started' is for the current tick.

Comment: Promise in its pure form would behave like that but `async` function pauses everything. So the last line waits for IIFE to finish.

Comment: @user3769778 — Calling an async function doesn't create a microtask. It is `then` and friends which do.

Answer (score 1):

`async` function returns a promise but the synchronous code inside `async` function is executed immediately (i.e. synchronously).
`await` statement pauses code execution until the promise which is given to it is resolved or rejected.

I always compare `async` function behaviour with the `Promise`'s [`executor` param](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters) behaviour. `executor` function is called immediately i.e. synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not doing anything asynchronous. The `printHello` method executes synchronously.
Prefixing a function with `async` just make sure that it returns a Promise. You could replace it with callback and it will work the same way, as callback will return immediately without waiting for the next tick of the event loop.

So if you want your code to behave the way you want it to, then you will have to wrap it around with a setTimeout or setImmediate call.

```
async function printHello() {
      setImmediate(() => {
        console.log('Hello World');
        return 5;
      });
  }
```

Comment: if i had a very big calculation in printHello and I wanted it not hang up my event loop then what options I have to make it async ? I thought marking any function async will make it async and the pass will go to next line.

Comment: Wrapping it inside setImmediate or process.nextTick  will make it appear asynchronous and won't immediately block the execution. But doing it in child process will be a better idea (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: While the code is not doing anything asynchronous, it is still behaving asynchronously as Promises (also the ones returned from async functions) guarantee asynchronous resolution. And you are right, offloading to another process seems to be the right approach here though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not asynchronous. That is this the problem. You need to return a promise that is always asynchronous.

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'foo',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'bar',
  }
];

function getUserById(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(users.filter(user => user.id === id)[0]);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function getUser(id) {
  let name;

  await getUserById(id).then(function(user) {
    name = user ? user.name : null;
  });

  console.log(name);
}

getUser(0);
console.log('console');
```

Answer (score 0):

All guys have given plenty helpful answer, but I will need to write an answer for this to help people who come up with a similar mentality as me : Just by marking a function async [or wrapping it in Promise] will not make your CPU intensive code to run as asynchronous fuct in nodejs.

My understanding prior to this problem, was that we can just put async before a function and put all heavy task on it. Aysnc will some how let nodejs event loop know once its finished [returned]. And I use to think it does this all things under the hood via spawning threads.

But this understanding is incorrect. Node is single threaded, if you ever going to write your code. Do never ever put any thing heavy task on nodejs.

Consider this express app:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.use('/name/:name',(req,res)=>{
    if(req.params['name']==='John'){
        res.end(timeConsumingFunct(2000).toString())
    }else{
        res.end(timeConsumingFunct(10000).toString())
    }
})


function timeConsumingFunct(ms) {//simulating CPU intensive work
    var start = Date.now(),
        now = start;
    while (now - start < ms) {
      now = Date.now();
    }
    return ms/1000;
}

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('Server started at : http://localhost:3000')
})
```

Now if you access : `http://localhost:3000/name/Tom` first and then `http://localhost:3000/name/John` in your browser, Mr.John will need to wait for total of 12 seconds minimum.
These is because Node js is single threaded no matter you use async or a Promise to wrap your `timeConsumingFunct` it will hung up entire flow.

The only way to make it truly async will be to use child process or worker api or write it in C++ .

Whatever you write as a JS is always synchronous and its going to hang up all the requests, know that before you think you can make any thing aysnc in nodejs.